# How can I include post teasers in my installation?

Tags: haskell, scope, hakyll

I'm following [the official instructions on the Hakyll site](https://jaspervdj.be/hakyll/tutorials/using-teasers-in-hakyll.html#gluing-together) to get post teasers up and running on my site. Unfortunately, I've hit a snag, and the instructions aren't much help.

I'm getting an out-of-scope error for the `item` value referenced in this snippet:

```
loadAndApplyTemplate
     "template/postitem.html"
     (teaserField "teaser" "content" <> defaultContext)
     item
```

When embedding it into my `site.hs`. On a side note for reproducibility's sake, it also wasn't made clear where the `<>` operator came from; this required the import of one of Literate Haskell's modules.

It's completely unclear where this reference to `item` came from, and because it's a fairly common word, I have to sift through thousands of results even when using `find` and `grep` on my machine.

What should I declare or import to gain access to `item` here?

Comment: `(<>)` is from [`Data.Monoid`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#v:-60--62-).

Comment: @JanTojnar I looked it up on Hoogle, and it was available in both `template-haskell Language.Haskell.TH.PprLib` and `pretty Text.PrettyPrint.HughesPJ, pretty Text.PrettyPrint`.

Comment: Most often, you will see `(<>)` used as `mappend`. For example, it can be used for joining [`Text`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.2.1/docs/Data-Text.html#t:Text) or, as in your example, for building [`Context`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hakyll-4.9.5.0/docs/Hakyll-Web-Template-Context.html#t:Context), both of which are `Monoid` instances.

Comment: Actually, in modern Haskell, `(<>)` is an operation on [`Semigroup`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Semigroup.html#t:Semigroup)

Comment: Honest question: is this particularly relevant beyond semantics? The operators from `Language.Haskell` and `Text.PrettyPrint` both seem to do what I need them to do.

Comment: They really should not work at all. They are defined to work on `Doc`: `(<>) :: Doc -> Doc -> Doc`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tutorial page isn't a complete example.  `item` isn't a reference to some function. It's just a placeholder name for an [`Item`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hakyll-4.9.4.0/docs/Hakyll-Core-Item.html#t:Item).  Usually you'll get it from [`pandocCompiler`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hakyll-4.9.4.0/docs/Hakyll-Web-Pandoc.html#v:pandocCompiler) or one of the [many other "compilers"](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hakyll-4.9.4.0/docs/Hakyll-Core-Compiler.html).  In this example, [`loadAndApplyTemplate`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hakyll-4.9.4.0/docs/Hakyll-Web-Template.html#v:loadAndApplyTemplate) is just like any other use of it. The only difference is that `$teaser$` will be bound to the teaser text in the template.

That said, this isn't that great of an example since you usually want to use the teaser text on page listing multiple posts.  This will probably involve using [`listField`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hakyll-4.9.4.0/docs/Hakyll-Web-Template-Context.html#v:listField) to make a collection of posts that you will iterate upon in the template.  For example, this is the rule for my index page:

```
match "index.html" $ do
    route idRoute
    compile $ do
        posts <- fmap (take indexRecentPostCount) . recentFirst =<< loadAllSnapshots postsPattern "postContent"
        let indexCtx =
                constField "title" "Home" <>
                baseCtx

        getResourceBody
            >>= applyAsTemplate (listField "posts" (teaserField "teaser" "postContent" <> postCtx) (return posts) <> indexCtx)
            >>= loadAndApplyDefaultTemplate indexCtx
            >>= relativizeUrls
```

The "item" in this case is what [`getResourceBody`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hakyll-4.9.4.0/docs/Hakyll-Core-Compiler.html#v:getResourceBody) returns, i.e. the body of `index.html`.  This binds `$posts$` to a list of posts.  Ignoring the metadata, my `index.html` is just:

```
$for(posts)$
    $partial("templates/teaser.html")$
$endfor$
```

`$teaser$` is then bound in the `template/teaser.html` template.